# SQL Server The operating system returned error 21 (The device is not ready.) - can I recover without restarting the server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

So I have found the related questions and answers about how to avoid having a disk not ready issue when SQL Server starts, which appears to be the cause of the OS error 21 (Device not ready) error when trying to use this database.  And I've read that restarting the sql server with the drives up and available will fix it.  Has anyone figured out a way to "fix" this issue which is occurring with just one db without restarting the server?

I've tried taking this one db offline, I've tried detaching the db.  Even detaching the DB requires the server to find and have access to the files in the first place?  Honestly I'm not entirely sure why SQL Server puts it in online state when it could not read the files successfully at startup time?

For those who have a DB in this state, and where it would be painful to bring the whole DB server down briefly, is there any other recourse?

Today I'm having the issue with on DB in SQL Server 2014, not sure if the answer would be different in later versions.

Comment: What _state_ is the problem database in now?

Comment: You could try by restarting SQL service only

Comment: The state appeared to be online.  Using SSMS, I cannot list the tables, I cannot run a query against this table.  I tried taking it offline.  I tried detaching it.  So it appears as "online" but everything one tries to do with regard to this database fails.

Comment: McNets - That was the ultimate recourse.  I wanted to avoid shutting down the SQL service as other databases were active with connections to them.  But it was not terribly disruptive to break those connections by stopping/starting the sql server.  But it seems it should not be necessary to force SQL server to re-attempt communication with that particular DB's underlying files.